# $cordovaFileTransfer.download doesn't work after Xcode Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I create a cordova application with ionic and ngCordova.
My application is simple : download a picture

My code is :

```
var from = 'http://www.diana.dti.ne.jp/~june1/perfume/perfume_voce.jpg';
var to = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'perfume.jpg';
var trustHosts = true;
var opt = {};

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(from, to, opt, trustHosts)
  .then(function(result) {

    // Image Success!
    alert('success');

  }, function(err) {

    // Image Error
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + err.code);

  }, function (progress) {

    // Image Progress

  });
```

I want to download this picture : http://www.diana.dti.ne.jp/~june1/perfume/perfume_voce.jpg
on documentsDirectory

I used this code on 2 computers (Apple) and before Xcode update, there isn't error.

Last week I updated Xcode on my 1st computer and I get this error :

**An error has occurred: Code = 3**

This is the doc of Cordova : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#user-content-constants

This error is because cordova block access of external source.

I continue to used my 2nd computer because it's was ok, but today I updated Xcode too. And now I have the same error.

Cordova block access of external source.
To confirm that, i try to transfert local picture to documentsDirectory and it's work.

```
var from = cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'www/original.jpg';
var to = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'perfume.jpg';
var trustHosts = true;
var opt = {};

$cordovaFileTransfer.download(from, to, opt, trustHosts)
  .then(function(result) {

    // Image Success!
    alert('success');

  }, function(err) {

    // Image Error
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + err.code);

  }, function (progress) {

    // Image Progress

  });
```

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.test5119111" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>test5</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />

  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />

  <feature name="File">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
  </feature>

  <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
  </feature>


  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>

  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />

  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />

  <feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
  </feature>

  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Can you help me ?
Where is my error and why after Xcode update, $cordovaFileTransfer.download doesn't work ?

Thanks you so much
(And sorry for my bed english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@seikida,
You have hit the three big issues, two from this weekend.

<s>1. Apple updated iOS devices to iOS9. Cordova, Phonegap and Ionic do not officially support iOS9 YET. This may not be a problem for you.</s>
 2. If you do NOT set the compiler version for your APP, you automatically get the latest version. If you do this, then you MUST use *white-list*, the *white-list* plugin, and CSP. You can avoid the white-list by using compiler version before 4.0.0, like 3.7.0
 3. Over the weekend, the default compiler were set to cli-5.2.0. This forces you to use *white-list* also. The fix is below

Here are additional details about your issues.

### 1. iOS9 is now supported

As of **Nov 2, 2015**, iOS 9 is supported by Cordova

*Apache Cordova iOS 3.9.2*
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/02/cordova-ios-3-9-2.html

### 1. No support for iOS9 YET!

**PhoneGap Build iOS 9 Support Status**

- Sept 23, 2015
- http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-build-ios-9-support-status
- Top line: iOS 9 is **NOT** officially supported until Cordova-iOS 4.0.0, which the Cordova team is hard at work on. However some issues can be solved with some simple configuration changes.

  Regardless, of what you are using, as the forum post states iOS 9 is not officially supported until Cordova-iOS 4.0.0. This means, create a work around, or wait until it is officially supported. OR file a bug report with cordova. OR wait until someone else creates a work around.

  This applies ONLY if you are using iOS 9.0.1

  ### 2. Not setting compiler version

From the *Phonegap Build* Forum, [Petra Adds](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/no-support-for-ios9-yet#reply_16160589):

> I would add: without announcement, PGB changed the default PGB-version from 3.7.0 to cli-5.2.0. This causes all those who have not set 'phonegap-version' in config.xml to be confronted with the sudden need of splashscreen and whitelist plugins and additional whitelisting specifications in config and html.
>
> Also, several plugins seem not to build correctly with cli-5.2.0, causing log file error messages about "Class ***.java".

FWIW: *Phonegap Build* [admitted to as much in this tweet](https://twitter.com/jessemonroy650/status/648313365505310720)

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading error.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
>   http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let use say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. This CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)

Comment: Oh it's not support YET!

Thanks you for this informations. So, I have a other question: How can I build my application on older iOS version ?

Comment: @seikida, FWIW, you CAN build for iOS9, you just won't get much official support - yet. Otherwise, you can just build as you normally would, just do not expect much help when testing with iOS9. ALSO, you should know that this past weekend Apple did start the usual "rolling updates". I got my notice, but I have not updated. We can likely expect that iOS9 support for Cordova/Phonegap to be available in a few weeks.

Comment: On your request to build applications for older iOS versions, You can modify your `.plist` file and add a `MinimumOSVersion`. I have read as much, but I do not know how to do that. [This link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/is_there_a_way_to_specify_the_minimum_ios_requrement_for_ios) discusses it. If this is what you are looking for you will want to ask more questions with the [Google Group for Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap). They likely know.

Comment: thank you for your help, really. I try to edit .plist file but it's still don't work... I updated iOS Simulator 8.4.0 and my application work on this simulator (but don't work on iOS Simulator 9.0.0). I very don't understand. Also, before to update iPhone to 9.0.0 I build my application on my boss iPhone and now, this application still working on my boss iPhone (iOS 9.0.0) but don't work on my iPhone (iOS 9.0.0) and work on my iPad (iOS 8.4.0)

Comment: MinimumOSVersion is not the max version. have I to use a previous version of Cordova? (I don't know, I am asking you). Maybe previous version of Cordova will force to use iOS 8.4.0. No ?

Comment: I use ionic plateform, so cordova > 4.0.2 is available.

Comment: @seikida, `MinimumOSVersion` is to see the least version of OS you will work with. See the official documentation for more [MinimumOSVersion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html). On the previous version of Cordova, I do not know.

Comment: @seikida, I do not know `ionic`. may ask the question on the [ionic form](http://forum.ionicframework.com/)